# Sorting nodes with PostgreSQL ltree

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree

Let's say I have a tree stored using ltree:

```
   id   |   path   |   sort   
------------------------------
0       |0         |1
1       |0.1       |2
2       |0.1.2     |3
3       |0.1.3     |1
4       |0.1.4     |2
5       |0.5       |3
6       |0.6       |1
```

I want to select nodes so that:

1. child nodes appear right after the parent node;
2. sibling nodes that has lesser "sort" value appear first;

Like this:

```
   id   |   path   |   sort   
------------------------------
0       |0         |1
6       |0.6       |1
1       |0.1       |2
3       |0.1.3     |1
4       |0.1.4     |2
2       |0.1.2     |3
5       |0.5       |3
```

The first requirement is possible with `ORDER BY path`, but I don't know how to implement the second, is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am solving this with a second ltree `sort_path` and some triggers.

Ultimately you will sort on the sort_path tree whose values are based on an lpad of the sort column of all the ancestors plus the lpad of the sort column of the current row.

```
   id   |   path   |   rank   |  sort_path
--------------------------------------------
0       |0         |1         | 0001
6       |0.6       |1         | 0001.0001
1       |0.1       |2         | 0001.0002
3       |0.1.3     |1         | 0001.0002.0001
4       |0.1.4     |2         | 0001.0002.0002
2       |0.1.2     |3         | 0001.0002.0003
5       |0.5       |3         | 0001.0003
```

BTW even the simple path sort you have is not quite right, you will have trouble as soon as you hit double digit path segments since the path sort is alpha-based, not numeric.

Note that a complete solution includes a trigger that recalculates the sort_path value for all descendants when the sort value is changed for any parent node row.

Example implementation:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS ltree;

CREATE TABLE tree_nodes (path LTREE, rank INT, sort_path LTREE);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_sort_path(tree_path LTREE, sibling_rank INT) RETURNS LTREE AS $$
DECLARE
  sort_ranks TEXT[];
  sort_path LTREE;
  ancestor RECORD;
BEGIN
  -- Default to the segment text (prepended with underscore).
  -- If some ancestors are missing, this ensures the children will still sort together.
  FOR iterator IN 1..NLEVEL(tree_path) LOOP
    sort_ranks[iterator] := '_' || SUBPATH(tree_path, iterator-1, 1)::TEXT;
  END LOOP;
  -- Format a sort rank path segment for each ancestor.
  FOR ancestor IN
    SELECT NLEVEL(tree_nodes.path) AS level, tree_nodes.rank FROM tree_nodes
      WHERE tree_nodes.path @> tree_path AND tree_nodes.path != tree_path
  LOOP
    sort_ranks[ancestor.level] := LPAD(ancestor.rank::TEXT, 4, '0');
  END LOOP;
  -- Format a final sort rank path segment for this leaf node.
  sort_ranks[NLEVEL(tree_path)] := LPAD(sibling_rank::TEXT, 4, '0');
  -- Convert array to LTREE path.
  SELECT STRING_AGG(padded_rank, '.')::LTREE INTO sort_path FROM
    (SELECT UNNEST(sort_ranks) AS padded_rank) path_ranks;

  RETURN sort_path;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sort_paths() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  has_changed BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  has_changed := TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND (OLD.path IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.path OR OLD.rank IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.rank);
  IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE' OR has_changed) THEN
    UPDATE tree_nodes SET sort_path = calc_sort_path(path, rank) WHERE OLD.path @> path;
  END IF;
  IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR has_changed) THEN
    UPDATE tree_nodes SET sort_path = calc_sort_path(path, rank) WHERE NEW.path @> path;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS on_rank_change ON tree_nodes;
CREATE TRIGGER on_rank_change AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON tree_nodes
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_sort_paths();
```